# What's the best way to expand a panel with JSF?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I would like to expand my panel that is working fine based on some condition(f.e. the value of a variable in my bean).

this is the code:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">collapse</button>

<div class="panel-body collapse" id="demo">
my text
</div>
```

I know that to expand and keep it expanded I should use the "in" like

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">collapse</button>

<div class="panel-body collapse in" id="demo">
my text
</div>
```

How can I manage it by code from JSF?

I did something like that and it works:

```
<div class="panel-body collapse #{Bean.toExpand}" id="demo">
my text
</div>
```

where #{Bean.toExpand} will contain the value "" or "in" in order to set during rendering that.

Do you think this is a good approach? Can it be improved?

Comment: Since you are using JSF, don't create plain HTML but use components like BootsFaces. For example https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/panels.jsf#programmable_collapseexpand_state

Answer (score 0):

Instead managing this from JSF code, my colleague suggested to do in javascript using JQUERY, and doing somenthing like this below

```
<h:outputScript>    

        function postscript() {

            if(${not empty Bean.list}){
                $('#demo').addClass("collapse");                    
            }else{
                $('#demo').removeClass("collapse");
            }
        }
        window.onload = postscript;

    </h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Just my opinion, but I would prefer the solution you used in your question.